# HTML5 Canvas non-zero fill-rule with subpaths

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to understand the effect created by some path drawing commands in HTML5 canvas. By default - if no parameters are given to the fill method non-zero fill-rule is active.

```
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(10,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,110);
ctx.lineTo(10,110);
ctx.lineTo(10,100);

ctx.moveTo(100,10);
ctx.lineTo(100,200);
ctx.lineTo(110,200);
ctx.lineTo(110, 10);
ctx.lineTo(100,10);
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(128,0,0,0.5)";
ctx.fill();
```

I'm drawing two subpaths (bars) crossing each other and fill the complete path with a fill command. Shouldn't the figure be completely filled (without a gap in the center) with a non-zero fill-rule. Where is the misunderstanding here?

https://jsfiddle.net/dqfp8dwr/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the second path to the following, this seems to produce what you want..

```
ctx.moveTo(100,10);
ctx.lineTo(110, 10);
ctx.lineTo(110,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,200);
ctx.lineTo(100,10);
```

As I think you mention there is a non-zero winding rule going on here, and from memory creating things anti-clockwise as how you had it originally causes the cutout to happen. Changing the second path to create clockwise prevents this from happening.

Found this video about it, its rather technical but might be of help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDtHBgBZyGI